# Can not open a text file just after creating it from webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am unable to open the file just after creating the file in c# webservice code .
The directory is not present initially. So the program creates the directory and the file. Then tries to open the file to write a line. But it fails to open the file. The error is the file is open in another process.

I tried to open the file from windows explorer. the file opens but error message is still coming.
I tried to delete  the folder C:\Test, it says file is open is in **WebDev.WebDevServer40.exe**

Any help please.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string saveFileUploaderName(string name)
    {
        string path = "c:\\Test";
        string filename = "Test.txt";
        string completeFileName = Path.Combine(path,filename);
        if(!File.Exists(completeFileName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            File.Create(completeFileName);
        }
        StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(completeFileName);
        writer.WriteLine(name);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
return "success";
}
```

Comment: Why do you wish to open text files on the server? Best practice to lock down file based access on a server, especially from processes like w3wp. Can you use a database instead?

Comment: Thanks. I am actually working on a classroom assignment. The question asks me to write something to text file from a web service.

Comment: Why do you require to create file separately? If you create StreamWriter in append mode, it will create one for you if it is not already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File.Create returns a stream, but you're discarding it.
So (I think!) you either need to use the returned stream, or explicitly close it before trying to open a new stream to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the file, try:

```
File.Create(completeFileName).Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) instead.

This will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Your code would be as simple as

```
[WebMethod]
public string saveFileUploaderName(string name)
{
    string path = "c:\\Test";
    string filename = "Test.txt";
    string completeFileName = Path.Combine(path,filename);
    File.AppendAllText(completeFileName, name);
    return "success";
}
```